# How to change a variable from another PHP file

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a website for an assignment. I know you can share variables by including them but how can I edit a variable from `var.php` in the `login.php` file?

I've already included the PHP file and echoed it and it showed the value I set in the var PHP but I want able to edit it.

`val.PHP` file code

```
$id = '0';
```

(It's just the `id` variable I want to edit)

`login.php` file code

```
include_once("val.PHP");
$id = $row['ID'];
```

So I want to have an output where it would let me change the variable to the account logged in, but it doesn't do anything? Any ideas?

Comment: You can *override* a variable from an included file... but not change what the variable is *in* the included file.

Comment: I see no problem, you can change `$id` in `login.php` and then echo the new value and it should print the new value, can you please show the code that you used to output `$id` ? and in which file  did you echoed it ?

Comment: @ObsidianAge of course one can patch the file... while using sessions might rather be the solution.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` instead.